# Activation of Windows 10 enterprise in an Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-10, entra-id, activation

I recently created an Azure VM using `Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1` image.
While creating, (since I was planning to buy a `Microsoft 365 F3` license seperately to activate this VM) I confirmed this in licensing section:
[image]

After finishing the deployment, I connected to it via RDP using the local administrator account.
(Didn't added the F3 licence yet with an Azure AD user).

And when I checked the activation settings, it already says that windows is activated.
[image]

Why is this so?
I didn't activated the Windows 10 enterprise manually with the M365 licence, but still it shows that it is activated.

Is this something like a trial period provided by microsoft?
Will it disable that activation after some time?

Should i do an Azure AD join of that VM and use M365 F3 license to activate that windows properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Automatically activates the Windows license of an Azure VM if that check box is checked during VM creation, but it has a grace period. If it is still not activated in the period, you will be asked to activate it. So it is better to activate using the M365 F3 license before the grace period ends.

You can find a discussion regarding this here :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/441711/windows-10-enterprise-in-an-azure-vm-activated-by.html